# semantic-ui modal Close - OK/Cancel Callback

Tags: semantic-ui

Is it possible to specify callback functions for Ok and Close button?

In case of JQuery Modal one could specify the callback functions at the time of initialization using the buttons dictionary. Does Semantic-ui modeal provide for something similar? How do i go for additional logic and close the model after Ok is pressed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add a .approve class (or alternative. see http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings to your 'OK' button to trigger the onApprove callback.

.close class for your Close button.

I have only be using semantic-ui for 2 weeks (and modals for a few hours) so caution required. Thanks mike123 for your answer.

```
$('.ui.modal.myModal').modal({
        onHide: function(){
            console.log('hidden');

        },
        onShow: function(){
            console.log('shown');
        },
        onApprove: function() {
            console.log('Approve');
            return validateModal()
        }
    }).modal('show');
```

Comment: If your answer is based on another user's answer, you should link to that answer.

Comment: This totally helped me!

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are after:

```
    $('.selector').modal({
        onHide: function(){
            console.log('hidden');
        },
        onShow: function(){
            console.log('shown');
        }
    }).modal('show');
```